# What can I do to be sure that a background service will not start twice?

Tags: android, android-service, alarmmanager, background-service

The past few days I am working on creating a background service and I noticed that quite a few people say that AlarmManager is the best way to go.

```
    AlarmManager am=(AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmManagerBroadcastReceiver.class);
    intent.putExtra(ONE_TIME, Boolean.FALSE);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
    //After after 5 seconds
    am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), 1000 * 5 ,
```

What I wish to know is how to make sure that if this code is ran twice the service won't start 2 times. Thank you for the help in advance!

Comment: What exactly do you mean by start twice? If a `Service` is already running the second start command will also be sent to the running `Service`. You cannot have two instances of the same `Service` at the same time. However if you want to perform some action only once regardless of how often the `Service` is started you can for example use `SharedPreferences` to save if the task has already been executed or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A service can't be started twice, it will remain running if you try to start it again.
See here: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#StartingAService

Edit:
However, everytime you start the service, the onStartCommand() method is called.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have used, for starting service after 30 seconds from current time,

```
  Intent intent = new Intent(DashboardScreen.this, ServiceClass.class);
  PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.getService(DashboardScreen.this, 0, intent, 0);
  AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
  alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), 30*1000, pintent);
```

Try it, and let me know what happen...

EDIT:

In your manifest.xml file

```
  <service android:enabled="true" android:name=".ServiceClass" />
```

Comment: if i restart my device then will this alarm manager will start service again without trying to open my app ? or may i need to start my service using boot_completed reciever